# Matching corresponding items in two lists for a menu

Tags: python

What this will print is:

```
Enter an action: 2
1. Bacon - 10
2. Cheese - 10
```

How do I get 12$ matched to the bacon, while 10 matched up with the cheese?

```
print('\nWelcome to the Shopping List App!\n')

item_list= []
item_price_list = []

while True:

    menu_selection = input(
    '''Please select one of the following:

    [1]: Add item
    [2]: View cart
    [3]: Remove item
    [4]: Compute total
    [5]: Quit

    Enter an action: ''')


    if menu_selection == '1':
        item = input('Add item: ').capitalize()
        item_list.append(item)
        item_price = input(f'What is the price of {item}? $')
        item_price_list.append(item_price)
        print(f'\n{item} has been added to you cart.\n')
        continue
    elif menu_selection == '2':
        
        for i, item in enumerate(item_list):
            print(f'{i+1}. {item} - {item_price}')
        for i, item_price in enumerate(item_price_list):
            pass
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a FAQ, not a forum. The title shouldn't be about who you are; it should be tersely describing a narrow, specific technical question that doesn't exist on our site already.

Comment: So -- what's the specific technical problem that needs to be solved to get the behavior you want? Once you know that you can simplify the code to a [mre] that reproduces that problem when run without changes and has nothing unrelated.

Comment: ...if the question is how to store your prices associated with items, think of using a dict to hold that mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) to hold data values.

```
item_dict = {}
while True:

    #...

    if menu_selection == '1':
        item = input('Add item: ').capitalize()
        item_price = input(f'What is the price of {item}? $')
        item_dict[item] = item_price
        print(f'\n{item} has been added to you cart.\n')
        continue
```

Once the values are assigned, the dictionary will look something like this

```
{'Bacon': 12, 'Cheese': 10}
```

Calling the items from the dictionary:

```
for key in item_dict:
    print(f'{key} - ${item_dict[key]}')
```